# changing child indentation and set border for toplevelitems in qtreewidget

Tags: c++, qt

i want to have a `treewidget` like first picture;
i tried to add item to `treewidget` and changing colour when they expand, what i've done is like second picture, but i need to set indentation like picture (for child with zero indent) and border for `toplevelitems`, or how can i change the entire colour of child(not from where its text start)
would you please help me how can i have a `qtreewidget` like picture?
thank you in advance

[image]

[image]